# How to construct a graph using Neural Structured Learning framework?

Tags: keras, tensorflow, regression, embeddings, graph-neural-network

My dataset (both features and label) consists of continuous variables. Dimension of features is `(12,)`. The number of samples are of 7th order of magnitude (about 11 million).
So in terms of a simple feed-forward neural network `input_shape` is `(12,)` and number of units of output layer is 1 using a ReLU activation.
I am currently using Adversarial Regularization in Neural Structured Learning framework to train my network which simply works out of the box if you don't have an explicit relation between your variables.

However what I would like to do is to use Graph Regularization. I'm trying to follow the given instructions from here (https://www.tensorflow.org/neural_structured_learning/tutorials/graph_keras_lstm_imdb) although the given problem is different, while mine is a regression one. Therefore, I would need to construct a graph. In order to do this, as far as I understand, I would need to create sample embeddings and then compare them in order to create the graph.

All information I have found up to now refer to word embeddings and, generally, classification problems. Converting my regression to classification problem by e.g. binning my data is not an option since every single value is important.

My main question is how to create these embeddings in my regression problem?

Thank you